# How to get org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to use the classes of the package org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.[(Link to Documentation)](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fpackage-summary.html) So far i found out, that this package is used for eclipse-plugins, but it is possible to use it for standalone applications, like showed [there](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/). But the libarys linked there only support jdk1.5. I also Installed the AST-View Plugin to Eclipse Neon but the jars cannot be found.

Since i want to use the functionality to parse Java code to AST and modify it, the newer version documented above would be nice to use.

Is there any way to download the desired package alone ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to maven repo [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.core). There are all the versions

Answer (score 0):

These jars are in Eclipse Neon but the versions (the part following the first `_`) will be different. This is assuming you are using one of the Eclipse Neon installs that supports Java development.

So, for example the Eclipse Neon.1 JDT plugin jar is `org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.12.1.v20160829-0950.jar`

Note that there is no separate `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom` jar, that package is in the ``org.eclipse.jdt.core_xxxx` jar.